# Can my multi-user MVC web application print to a Zebra label printer?

Tags: c#, printing, zebra-printers

I have read a few questions on here about printing to Zebra printers 
([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887961/can-you-direct-pdf-print-to-a-zebra-printer), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821461/how-can-i-print-to-a-label-printer-from-a-web-page)). I understand that it's best to send the printer code in ZPL, but it seems that this requires knowing which printer will be used. Our application will be accessed by any number of users with any number of different, distinct Zebra printers.

Can anyone help or point me to some documentation? How can a website send any Zebra printer instructions to print?

Comment: Printing is handed off by the browser to local operating system functions.  The website might define a "printed version" via CSS with alternate layouts or black and white instead of color, but the specific printer a user has is not a website concern.

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity.

Comment: A printer installed on the clients, or on the server?

Comment: If the printer is connected to the PC via USB you shouldn't have problems. It will work as a normal printer